# How to create a curved line vector plot of a triangle in Python?

Tags: python, geometry, smoothing, fractals

### Question

Suppose one has 3 random coordinates with 3 random functions that describe the continuous lines between them*, how would one create a vector plot in Python that allows for smooth lines after infinite zooming in?

### Example

The functions should be rotated and translated from their specification to map onto the edge/line in the geometry. For example, one curved line may be specified as `-x(x-5)=0` which describes the line from `(x,y)` coordinates:`(2,6)` to `(5,2)` (which has length 5). Another curved line from `(x,y)` coordinates:`(2,2)` to `(2,6)` may be specified as `sin(x/4*pi)=0`. One can assume all bulges point outward (of the triangle in this case).

### Approach

I can perform a translation and rotation of the respective functions to the lines of the coordinates, and then save the `plt` as a `.eps` or `.pdf`, however before doing that, I thought it would be wise to ask how these functions are represented and how these plots are generated, as I expect the `dpi` setting may simply turn it into a (very) high resolution plot, instead of something that still provides smooth lines after infinite scrolling.

### Doubt

I can imagine using a sinusoid does not allow for infinite smooth scrolling as they may be stored numerically. If the representation is finite for sinusoids but analytical/symbolic for polynomials, I would be happy to constraint this question to polynomials only to get smooth infinitely scrollable images (like fractals).

Comment: Postscript (used in EPS and PDF) describes curves as Beziers.  If you can translate your edges to Beziers, then they will be infinitely scalable.  Pyplot doesn't do that.  Now, as long as you have the Pyplot window open, you can scale it infinitely, but once you save to an EPS, it's going to be more rigid.

Comment: Thank you! I found this MWE of Beziers: https://github.com/simoncozens/beziers.py (`pip install beziers`) and it seems like I could sample `n` points per function, until I am satisfied with how well the Bezier matches the actual function. Then I could rotate and translate the coordinates, and create the respective Beziers from those points. Once I have completed this task, I will post an answer.